# How to correctly set up input parameter of url in an HTTP GET request?

Tags: python, https

Write a function named "variable_get" that takes a string as a parameter representing part of a path of a url and returns the response of an HTTPS GET request to the url "http://python.org/(input)" as a string where (input) is the input parameter of this function.

```
import urllib2
def variable_get(input1):
    content = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/input1').read()
    return content
```

My question is how to correctly set up input parameter of url in an HTTP GET request?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

In Python > 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-use-of-globals-or-locals):

```
from urllib import request
def variable_get(input1):
    url = f'http://python.org/{input1}'
    print(url)
    content = request.urlopen(url).read()
    return content

variable_get('somePath')
```

should print `'http://python.org/somePath'`

Comment: Yes, in Python3 is no urllib2. You need to use [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Comment: That 'f' letter on line 3 would give you a syntax error.